# How to set a default value for "Edit control box" in a Dialog that is added to MFC Doc/Frame project

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I added a extra Dialog (`TestDialog`) in a MFC doc/frame project (Single doc, MFC, VC++2010 project) That dialog has a "EDIT Control" (`IDC_EDIT1, m_EditBox1 etc`) box. After starting the  MFC program from the DOC/frame Menu I selected the testdialog which then popup or start.

But Whenver I start that Testdialog the EDIT Control box appear as empty and I have to type a starting value (say 100) so that I can press a button (inside testdialog) that runs a program which accept 100 as input.

How and where I can add a starting value say 100 to this Edit control so that when testdialog will open the EDIT control box already will have that default vale ( i,e 100).

TestDialog.cpp file shows

```
CTestDialog::CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CDialogEx(CTestDialog::IDD, pParent)
, testdlg(0)

{
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use *OnInitDialog ()* to set any dialog values before the dialog displays.  There are multiple ways to accomplish it.  Here are two...

1. You can use *SetWindowText* to insert a string value into the control.
2. Define the control with a member variable that accepts a CString value.   Assign a default value to the variable.  OnInitDialog should handle updating the field.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for your reply. The problem is my MFC project (say name : R) originally ia  DOC/Menu type and I MYSELF added a extra dialog in it . SO there is no InitDialog() in the files generated by the project (R.cpp, RDoc.cpp, RView.cpp, MainFrm.cpp, TestDialog.cpp,stdafx.cpp and the corresponding 4 hearder file (same name with .h extension). Where should I add the OnitDialog for a TestDialog.cpp ?

Comment: @user3009750 OnInitDialog is a member of CDialogEx. Your CTestDialog presumably inherits from CDialogEx and should override this method. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwz35s59.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Go to InitDialog function of your test dialog class (if InitDialog() not already present, override it).

Then , Do this:

```
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowTextA("100");
```

Comment: @foobar - how to set 'int' variable in this fashion?

Comment: @Chetan Easiest would be to cast your int into CString using Format function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you !! I finally did it like that
a) In Testdialog.h file in CtestDialog class I added I declared OnInitDialog() by adding a line -->  virtual BOOL OnInitDialog( )

```
    class CTestDialog : public CDialogEx
    {

    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CTestDialog)

    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog( );

    public:

    CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~CTestDialog();

    public:

    Private:
}
```

and then in TestDialog.cpp I added

```
BOOL CTestDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
   CDialog::OnInitDialog();

   m_EditBox1.SetWindowText(_T("100"));

  //  GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowTextA("100");


     return TRUE;
}
```

And then everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbe but this is a method I found working... (don't know how correct it is..)
I add a variable to the "EDIT control" and use a constructor member initialisation list (here `i_num_days(91)` sets the `i_num_days` to 91:

```
CMyDlg::CMyDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
  : CDialogEx(CMyDlg::IDD, pParent)
  , i_num_days(91)
  , ..
{
  m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}
```

and then in the following it is connected to the "Edit control":

```
void CMyDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
  CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
  DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT_NUMBER_OF_DAYS, i_num_days);
  DDV_MinMaxInt(pDX, i_num_days, 1, 366);
  ..
}
```

If someone knows this to be wrong, please correct me...

Answer (score 0):

If you use setwindowtext(L" "); then still the edit control's caret will be shown after a space...in order to get out of this situation..u can go for this option..place this code in the event handler of the edit control

```
CString name=L" ";
GetDlgItem(IDC_Editname,name);

if(name==L" ")
{
    CEdit* pname=(CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDITNAME);
    pname->SetFocus();
    pname->SetSel(0,-1);
    pname->SetSel(0);
}
```